# What is the most useful R trick?

Tags: r

In order to share some more tips and tricks for [**R**](http://www.r-project.org), what is your single-most useful feature or trick?  Clever vectorization?  Data input/output?  Visualization and graphics?  Statistical analysis?  Special functions?  The interactive environment itself?

One item per post, and we will see if we get a winner by means of votes.

[Edit 25-Aug 2008]:  So after one week, it seems that the simple `str()` won the poll. As I like to recommend that one myself, it is an easy answer to accept.

Comment: @Dirk: "community wiki" means "community-owned", its not a synonym for "poll question". Don't listen to the community wiki police.

Comment: Considering http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/11743#11743 it should be CW.

Comment: CW bullying again.  I'll see your meta-SO and raise you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down

Comment: @ars: its a question that *does not have a definite answer*. Ergo make it CW.

Comment: @JD Long hilarious comment. unfortunately it was hidden behind the fold. I mean answering tough R questions doesn't really pay stack-rep wise. So it´s ok to me if guys who set up nice questions that put R on the map finally get some credit. Besides this is certainly more useful the R users than a what´s your favorite C trick question would be to C programmers...

Comment: Well it worked for me...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`str()` tells you the structure of any object.

Comment: Python uses `dir()` - makes more sense.

Comment: Ah, `str` is also short for `string` in many languages.

Comment: Why not `class()`? It seems to reveal similar type of information. Why are there two such similar commands?

Comment: `class()` is just a small part of the information that `str()` displays

Answer (score 64):

One very useful function I often use is dput(), which allows you to dump an object in the form of R code.

```
# Use the iris data set
R> data(iris)
# dput of a numeric vector
R> dput(iris$Petal.Length)
c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 
1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.7, 1.5, 1, 1.7, 1.9, 
1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 
1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 1.4, 1.6, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 4.7, 
4.5, 4.9, 4, 4.6, 4.5, 4.7, 3.3, 4.6, 3.9, 3.5, 4.2, 4, 4.7, 
3.6, 4.4, 4.5, 4.1, 4.5, 3.9, 4.8, 4, 4.9, 4.7, 4.3, 4.4, 4.8, 
5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.8, 3.7, 3.9, 5.1, 4.5, 4.5, 4.7, 4.4, 4.1, 4, 
4.4, 4.6, 4, 3.3, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 3, 4.1, 6, 5.1, 5.9, 5.6, 
5.8, 6.6, 4.5, 6.3, 5.8, 6.1, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 5, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 
6.7, 6.9, 5, 5.7, 4.9, 6.7, 4.9, 5.7, 6, 4.8, 4.9, 5.6, 5.8, 
6.1, 6.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.6, 6.1, 5.6, 5.5, 4.8, 5.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.1, 
5.9, 5.7, 5.2, 5, 5.2, 5.4, 5.1)
# dput of a factor levels
R> dput(levels(iris$Species))
c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")
```

It can be very useful to post easily reproducible data chunks when you ask for help, or to edit or reorder the levels of a factor.

Answer (score 42):

head() and tail() to get the first and last parts of a dataframe, vector, matrix, function, etc. Especially with large data frames, this is a quick way to check that it has loaded ok.

Answer (score 38):

One nice feature:  Reading data uses ***connections*** which can be local files, remote files accessed via http, pipes from other programs or more.

As a simple example, consider this access for N=10 random integers between min=100 and max=200 from [random.org](http://www.random.org) (which supplies true random numbers based on atmospheric noise rather than a pseudo random number generator):

```
R> site <- "http://random.org/integers/"         # base URL
R> query <- "num=10&min=100&max=200&col=2&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new"
R> txt <- paste(site, query, sep="?")            # concat url and query string
R> nums <- read.table(file=txt)                  # and read the data
R> nums                                          # and show it
   V1  V2
1 165 143
2 107 118
3 103 132
4 191 100
5 138 185
R>
```

As an aside, the [random](http://cran.r-project.org/package=random) package provides several convenience functions for accessing [random.org](http://www.random.org).

Comment: BTW-- I'd suggest that you *should* make selfanswers CW if (1) you post them promptly and (2) you don't make the question CW. Otherwise it looks a bit like you're trying to game the rep system. YMMV and all that.

Comment: It's not gaming the system, just getting things started.  He's still free to accept any other answer.

Comment: @ars: He's free to accept this one. Nor am I going to attempt to force him to wiki it if he won;t take my advice. But I won't post a prepared selfanswer without marking it wiki, and I won't vote for one without it either. Take that for what it's worth.

Comment: good points all. Some self answers are good for discussion. We do this in real life too.

Comment: @Dirk: it is wholly acceptable, even encouraged by Jeff and Joel, to answer your own question. There is NO requirement, not even an informal one, to make your answer CW. You're clearly not gaming the system. Once again, just ignore the community wiki police.

Comment: I have to agree that part of the sites purpose is to provide best answers for common problems and a general resource. Posing a questions and providing a good answer can help bolster a topic. This is especially useful with new/small tags such as R.

Answer (score 35):

I find I am using `with()` and `within()` more and more. No more `$` littering my code and one doesn't need to start attaching objects to the search path. More seriously, I find `with()` etc make the *intention* of my data analysis scripts much clearer.

```
> df <- data.frame(A = runif(10), B = rnorm(10))
> A <- 1:10 ## something else hanging around...
> with(df, A + B) ## I know this will use A in df!
 [1]  0.04334784 -0.40444686  1.99368816  0.13871605 -1.17734837
 [6]  0.42473812  2.33014226  1.61690799  1.41901860  0.8699079
```

`with()` sets up an environment within which the R expression is evaluated. `within()` does the same thing but allows you to modify the data object used to create the environment.

```
> df <- within(df, C <- rpois(10, lambda = 2))
> head(df)
           A          B C
1 0.62635571 -0.5830079 1
2 0.04810539 -0.4525522 1
3 0.39706979  1.5966184 3
4 0.95802501 -0.8193090 2
5 0.76772541 -1.9450738 2
6 0.21335006  0.2113881 4
```

Something I didn't realise when I first used `within()` is that you have to do an assignment as part of the expression evaluated **and** assign the returned object (as above) to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 34):

### Data Input trick = RGoogleDocs package

http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleDocs/

I have found Google spreadsheets to be a fantastic way for all collaborators to be on the same page. Furthermore, Google Forms allows one to capture data from respondents and effortlessly write it to a google spreadsheet. Since data changes frequently and is almost never final it is far preferable for R to read a google spreadsheet directly than to futz with downloading csv files and reading them in.

```
# Get data from google spreadsheet
library(RGoogleDocs)
ps <-readline(prompt="get the password in ")
auth = getGoogleAuth("me@gmail.com", ps, service="wise")
sheets.con <- getGoogleDocsConnection(auth)
ts2=getWorksheets("Data Collection Repos",sheets.con)
names(ts2)
init.consent <-sheetAsMatrix(ts2$Sheet1,header=TRUE, as.data.frame=TRUE, trim=TRUE)
```

I cannot rembember which but one or two of the following commands takes several seconds.

1. getGoogleAuth
2. getGoogleDocsConnection
3. getWorksheets

Answer (score 27):

Use backticks to reference non standard names.

```
> df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(5),y=runif(5))
> names(df) <- 1:2
> df
           1         2
1 -1.2035003 0.6989573
2 -1.2146266 0.8272276
3  0.3563335 0.0947696
4 -0.4372646 0.9765767
5 -0.9952423 0.6477714
> df$1
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "df$1"
> df$`1`
[1] -1.2035003 -1.2146266  0.3563335 -0.4372646 -0.9952423
```

In this case, df[,"1"] would also work. But back ticks work inside formulas!

```
> lm(`2`~`1`,data=df)

Call:
lm(formula = `2` ~ `1`, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          `1`  
     0.4087      -0.3440
```

[Edit]
Dirk asks why one would give invalid names? I don't know! But I certainly encounter this problem in practice fairly often. For example, using hadley's reshape package:

```
> library(reshape)
> df$z <- c(1,1,2,2,2)
> recast(df,z~.,id.var="z")
Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default
  z (all)
1 1     4
2 2     6
> recast(df,z~.,id.var="z")$(all)
Error: unexpected '(' in "recast(df,z~.,id.var="z")$("
> recast(df,z~.,id.var="z")$`(all)`
Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default
[1] 4 6
```

Comment: Ok, but _why_ would you need to replace syntactically valid names (like x or y) with invalid ones (like 1 or 2) requiring the backticks?

Comment: It's also useful in `read.table` when `check.names` is false - i.e. when you want to work with the original column names.

Answer (score 25):

Don't know how well known this is/isn't, but something that I've definitely taken advantage of are the pass-by-reference capabilities of environments.

```
zz <- new.env()
zz$foo <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
changer <- function(blah) {
   blah$foo <- 5
}
changer(zz)
zz$foo
```

For this example it doesn't make sense why it'd be useful, but if you're passing large objects around it can help.

Answer (score 23):

My new favorite thing is the foreach library.  It lets you do all of the nice apply things, but with a somewhat easier syntax:

```
list_powers <- foreach(i = 1:100) %do% {
  lp <- x[i]^i
  return (lp)
}
```

The best part is that if you are doing something that actually requires a significant amount of time, you can switch from `%do%` to `%dopar%` (with the appropriate backend library) to instantly parallelize, even across a cluster.  Very slick.

Answer (score 19):

I do a lot of basic manipulation of data, so here are two built-in functions ( **transform** , **subset** ) and one library ( **sqldf** ) that I use daily.

### create sample sales data

```
sales <- expand.grid(country = c('USA', 'UK', 'FR'),
                     product = c(1, 2, 3))
sales$revenue <- rnorm(dim(sales)[1], mean=100, sd=10)

> sales
  country product   revenue
1     USA       1 108.45965
2      UK       1  97.07981
3      FR       1  99.66225
4     USA       2 100.34754
5      UK       2  87.12262
6      FR       2 112.86084
7     USA       3  95.87880
8      UK       3  96.43581
9      FR       3  94.59259
```

### use transform() to add a column

```
## transform currency to euros
usd2eur <- 1.434
transform(sales, euro = revenue * usd2eur)

>
  country product   revenue     euro
1     USA       1 108.45965 155.5311
2      UK       1  97.07981 139.2125
3      FR       1  99.66225 142.9157
...
```

### use subset() to slice the data

```
subset(sales, 
       country == 'USA' & product %in% c(1, 2), 
       select = c('product', 'revenue'))

>
  product  revenue
1       1 108.4597
4       2 100.3475
```

### use sqldf() to slice and aggregate with SQL

The [sqldf package](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/) provides an SQL interface to R data frames

```
##  recast the previous subset() expression in SQL
sqldf('SELECT product, revenue FROM sales \
       WHERE country = "USA" \
       AND product IN (1,2)')

>
  product  revenue
1       1 108.4597
2       2 100.3475
```

Perform an aggregation or GROUP BY

```
sqldf('select country, sum(revenue) revenue \ 
       FROM sales \
       GROUP BY country')

>
  country  revenue
1      FR 307.1157
2      UK 280.6382
3     USA 304.6860
```

For more sophisticated map-reduce-like functionality on data frames, check out the [plyr](http://crantastic.org/packages/plyr) package.  And if find yourself wanting to pull your hair out, I recommend checking out [Data Manipulation with R](http://www.amazon.com/Data-Manipulation-R-Use/product-reviews/0387747303).

Answer (score 18):

```
?ave
```

Subsets of 'x[]' are averaged, where each subset consist of those
     observations with the same factor levels.
Usage:
     ave(x, ..., FUN = mean)

I use it all the time. (e.g. [in this answer here at so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301759/mixed-merge-in-r-subscript-solution/1302334#1302334))

Comment: how does this differ from tapply(x, factor, fun) ??

Comment: @Tomas ave preserves ordering and length. so you can, for example, add a vector of group means to a dataset, in one step.

Answer (score 18):

A way to speed up code and eliminate for loops.

instead of for loops that loop through a dataframe looking for values.
just take a subset of the df with those values, much quicker.

so instead of:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (df$column[i] == x) {
    df$column2[i] <- y
    or any other similiar code
  }
}
```

do something like this:

```
df$column2[df$column1 == x] <- y
```

that base concept is applicable extremely often and is a great way to get rid of for loops

Comment: There is a small trap here that used to catch me up all the time.  If df$column1 contains NA values, subsetting using == will pull out any values that equal x *and* any NAs.  To avoid this, use "%in%" instead of "==".

Comment: Matt you're absolutely right and it's something that I hate, I like your method though. I usually check the column for NAs and then remove them with a quick function i made that takes a dataframe column and returns the dataframe minus rows with NAs in just that column.

Comment: essentially, i pare a dataframe down to the columns i need to have values then use na.omit to get the correct rows and then subset the original dataset with only those rows. Just using na.omit would remove any row with any NA, I could be mistaken though.

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes you need to `rbind` multiple data frames.  `do.call()` will let you do that (someone had to explain this to me when bind I asked this question, as it doesn't appear to be an obvious use).

```
foo <- list()

foo[[1]] <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=11:15)
foo[[2]] <- data.frame(a=101:105, b=111:115)
foo[[3]] <- data.frame(a=200:210, b=300:310)

do.call(rbind, foo)
```

Comment: Good call: I find that this is often simpler than using `unsplit`.

Answer (score 16):

In R programming (not interactive sessions), I use `if (bad.condition) stop("message")` a *lot*.  Every function starts with a few of these, and as I work through computations, I pepper these in, too.  I guess I got into the habit from using `assert()` in C.  The benefits are two-fold.  First, it's a lot faster to get working code with these checks in place.  Second, and probably more important, it is a lot easier to work with existing code when you see these checks on every screen in your editor.  You won't have to wonder whether `x>0`, or trust a comment stating that it is ... you'll *know*, from a glance, that it is.

PS. my first post here.  Be gentle!

Comment: Not a bad habit, and R offers yet another way:  `stopfifnot(!bad.condition)` which is more concise.

Answer (score 13):

The `traceback()` function is a must when you have an error somewhere and do not understand it readily. It will print a trace of the stack, very helpful as R is not very verbose by default.

Then setting `options(error=recover)` will allow you to "enter" into the function raising the error and try and understand what happens exactly, as if you had full control over it and could put a `browser()` in it.

These three functions can really help debugging your code.

Comment: `options(error=recover)` is my favorite debugging method.

Answer (score 12):

I'm really surprised no one has posted about apply, tapply, lapply, and sapply. A general rule I use when doing stuff in R is that if I have a for loop that is doing data processing or simulations, I try to factor it out and replace it with an *apply. Some people shy away from the *apply functions because they think only single parameter functions can be passed in. Nothing could be further from the truth! Like passing around functions with parameters as first class objects in Javascript, you do this in R with anonymous functions. For example:

```
 > sapply(rnorm(100, 0, 1), round)
  [1]  1  1  0  1  1 -1 -2  0  2  2 -2 -1  0  1 -1  0  1 -1  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0
 [26]  2  0 -1 -2  0  0  1 -1  1  5  1 -1  0  1  1  1  2  0 -1  1 -1  1  0 -1  1
 [51]  2  1  1 -2 -1  0 -1  2 -1  1 -1  1 -1  0 -1 -2  1  1  0 -1 -1  1  1  2  0
 [76]  0  0  0 -2 -1  1  1 -2  1 -1  1  1  1  0  0  0 -1 -3  0 -1  0  0  0  1  1


> sapply(rnorm(100, 0, 1), round(x, 2)) # How can we pass a parameter?
Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'x' not found


# Wrap your function call in an anonymous function to use parameters
> sapply(rnorm(100, 0, 1), function(x) {round(x, 2)})
  [1] -0.05 -1.74 -0.09 -1.23  0.69 -1.43  0.76  0.55  0.96 -0.47 -0.81 -0.47
 [13]  0.27  0.32  0.47 -1.28 -1.44 -1.93  0.51 -0.82 -0.06 -1.41  1.23 -0.26
 [25]  0.22 -0.04 -2.17  0.60 -0.10 -0.92  0.13  2.62  1.03 -1.33 -1.73 -0.08
 [37]  0.45 -0.93  0.40  0.05  1.09 -1.23 -0.35  0.62  0.01 -1.08  1.70 -1.27
 [49]  0.55  0.60 -1.46  1.08 -1.88 -0.15  0.21  0.06  0.53 -1.16 -2.13 -0.03
 [61]  0.33 -1.07  0.98  0.62 -0.01 -0.53 -1.17 -0.28 -0.95  0.71 -0.58 -0.03
 [73] -1.47 -0.75 -0.54  0.42 -1.63  0.05 -1.90  0.40 -0.01  0.14 -1.58  1.37
 [85] -1.00 -0.90  1.69 -0.11 -2.19 -0.74  1.34 -0.75 -0.51 -0.99 -0.36 -1.63
 [97] -0.98  0.61  1.01  0.55

# Note that anonymous functions aren't being called, but being passed.
> function() {print('hello #rstats')}()
function() {print('hello #rstats')}()
> a = function() {print('hello #rstats')}
> a
function() {print('hello #rstats')}
> a()
[1] "hello #rstats"
```

(For those that follow #rstats, I also posted this there).

Remember, use apply, sapply, lapply, tapply, and do.call! Take avantage of R's vectorization. You should never walk up to a bunch of R code and see:

```
N = 10000
l = numeric()
for (i in seq(1:N)) {
    sim <- rnorm(1, 0, 1)
    l <- rbind(l, sim)
}
```

Not only is this not vectorized, but the array structure in R is not grown as it is in Python (doubling size when space runs out, IIRC). So each rbind step must first grow l enough to accept the results from rbind(), then copy all over the previous l's contents. For fun, try the above in R. Notice how long it takes (you won't even need Rprof or any timing function). Then try

```
N=10000
l <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)
```

The following is better than the first version too:

```
N = 10000
l = numeric(N)
for (i in seq(1:N)) {
    sim <- rnorm(1, 0, 1)
    l[i] <- sim
}
```

Comment: apply, sapply, lapply and tapply are useful. If you want to pass parameters to a named function like round, you can just pass it along with apply instead of writing an anonymous function. Try  "sapply(rnorm(10, 0, 1), round, digits=2)" which outputs "[1] -0.29  0.29  1.31 -0.06 -1.90 -0.84  0.21  0.02  0.23 -1.10".

Answer (score 11):

Upon Dirk's advice, I am posting single examples. I hope they are not too "cute" [clever, but I don't care] or trivial for this audience.

Linear models are the bread and butter of R. When the number of independent variables is high, one has two choices. The first is to it use lm.fit(), which receives the design matrix x and the response y as arguments, similarly to Matlab. The drawback to this approach is that the return value is a list of objects (fitted coefficients, residuals, etc), not an object of class "lm", which can be nicely summarized, used for prediction, stepwise selection, etc. The second approach is create a formula:

```
> A
           X1         X2          X3         X4         y
1  0.96852363 0.33827107 0.261332257 0.62817021 1.6425326
2  0.08012755 0.69159828 0.087994158 0.93780481 0.9801304
3  0.10167545 0.38119304 0.865209832 0.16501662 0.4830873
4  0.06699458 0.41756415 0.258071616 0.34027775 0.7508766
   ...

> (f=paste("y ~",paste(names(A)[1:4],collapse=" + ")))
[1] "y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4"

> lm(formula(f),data=A)

Call:
lm(formula = formula(f), data = A)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           X1           X2           X3           X4  
    0.78236      0.95406     -0.06738     -0.43686     -0.06644
```

Comment: How about if you pick one per post and illustrate with an example?  We can then keep going for days on end and post new examples with new commands... 

[ BTW: As I recall, you need  as.formula(paste(...))  for formula use. ]

Comment: You do not need the explicitly formula creation to cover all columns as the form "y ~ . - 1" covers it.  The "." means 'all columns except the dependent variable, and the '- 1' excludes the constant as in your example.

Comment: That's right for this specific example, but for X with ncols>>nrows, I often remove some independent variables, especially in the final stages of the analysis. In this case, creating a formula from the data frame names is still handy.

Answer (score 10):

You can assign a value returning from an if-else block.

Instead of, e.g.

```
condition <- runif(1) > 0.5
if(condition) x <- 1 else x <- 2
```

you can do

```
x <- if(condition) 1 else 2
```

Exactly how this works is deep magic.

Comment: You could also do this like x <- ifelse(condition, 1, 2), in which case each component is vectorized.

Comment: Shane, you could, but unless you really deeply grok what ifelse() does, you probably shouldn't! It's an easy one to misunderstand...

Comment: What is magical about that? That's just the way `if-then-else` expressions work in any functional language (not to be confused with `if-then-else` *statements*). Very similar to the ternary `?:` operator of C-like languages.

Answer (score 10):

As a total noob to R and a novice at stats I love `unclass()`
to print all elements of a data frame as an ordinary list.

It's pretty handy for a look at a complete data set all in one go to quickly eyeball any potential issues.

Answer (score 9):

`CrossTable()` from the `gmodels` package provides easy access to SAS- and SPSS-style crosstabs, along with the usual tests (Chisq, McNemar, etc.).  Basically, it's `xtabs()` with fancy output and some additional tests - but it does make sharing output with the heathens easier.

Comment: Nice!! I use gmodels quite a bit, but missed that one

Comment: Good answer, anything that can keep me away from excessive explanation of tables with the heathens is a good use of time.

Answer (score 7):

Definitively `system()`.
To be able to have access to all the unix tools (at least under Linux/MacOSX) from inside the R environment has rapidly become invaluable in my daily workflow.

Comment: That ties into my earlier comment about connections: you can also use pipe() to pass data from, or to, Unix commands. See `help(connections)` for details and examples.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an annoying workaround to convert a factor into a numeric. (Similar for other data types as well)

```
old.var <- as.numeric(levels(old.var))[as.numeric(old.var)]
```

Comment: Maybe you meant "into a characater" vector.  In which case  "as.character(old.var)"  is simpler.

Comment: I've always thought this advice (which can be read at ?factor) to be  misguided. You have to be sure old.var is a factor, and this will vary according on the options you set for the R session. Using as.numeric(as.character(old.var)) is both safer and cleaner.

Comment: Really not worth a downvote, but whatever. This works for me.

Comment: Ryan - Could you fix your code? If old.var <- factor(1:2); your code will give [1] "1" "2" (not numeric.) perhaps you meant as.numeric(levels(old.var)[old.var])?

Comment: Or slightly more efficiently: `as.numeric(levels(old.var))[old.var]`

Comment: What about: as.numeric(as.character(old.var)) ?

Comment: Thanks for editing. But you don't need the as.numeric inside the index. The reason: typeof(factor(1:3)) is integer. Damn you factors!

Answer (score 6):

Although this question has been up for a while I recently discovered a great trick on the [SAS and R blog](http://sas-and-r.blogspot.com/2010/01/example-721-write-function-to-simulate.html) for using the command `cut`.  The command is used to divide data into categories and I will use the iris dataset as an example and divide it into 10 categories:

```
> irisSL <- iris$Sepal.Length
> str(irisSL)
 num [1:150] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
> cut(irisSL, 10)
  [1] (5.02,5.38] (4.66,5.02] (4.66,5.02] (4.3,4.66]  (4.66,5.02] (5.38,5.74] (4.3,4.66]  (4.66,5.02] (4.3,4.66]  (4.66,5.02]
 [11] (5.38,5.74] (4.66,5.02] (4.66,5.02] (4.3,4.66]  (5.74,6.1]  (5.38,5.74] (5.38,5.74] (5.02,5.38] (5.38,5.74] (5.02,5.38]
 [21] (5.38,5.74] (5.02,5.38] (4.3,4.66]  (5.02,5.38] (4.66,5.02] (4.66,5.02] (4.66,5.02] (5.02,5.38] (5.02,5.38] (4.66,5.02]
 [31] (4.66,5.02] (5.38,5.74] (5.02,5.38] (5.38,5.74] (4.66,5.02] (4.66,5.02] (5.38,5.74] (4.66,5.02] (4.3,4.66]  (5.02,5.38]
 [41] (4.66,5.02] (4.3,4.66]  (4.3,4.66]  (4.66,5.02] (5.02,5.38] (4.66,5.02] (5.02,5.38] (4.3,4.66]  (5.02,5.38] (4.66,5.02]
 [51] (6.82,7.18] (6.1,6.46]  (6.82,7.18] (5.38,5.74] (6.46,6.82] (5.38,5.74] (6.1,6.46]  (4.66,5.02] (6.46,6.82] (5.02,5.38]
 [61] (4.66,5.02] (5.74,6.1]  (5.74,6.1]  (5.74,6.1]  (5.38,5.74] (6.46,6.82] (5.38,5.74] (5.74,6.1]  (6.1,6.46]  (5.38,5.74]
 [71] (5.74,6.1]  (5.74,6.1]  (6.1,6.46]  (5.74,6.1]  (6.1,6.46]  (6.46,6.82] (6.46,6.82] (6.46,6.82] (5.74,6.1]  (5.38,5.74]
 [81] (5.38,5.74] (5.38,5.74] (5.74,6.1]  (5.74,6.1]  (5.38,5.74] (5.74,6.1]  (6.46,6.82] (6.1,6.46]  (5.38,5.74] (5.38,5.74]
 [91] (5.38,5.74] (5.74,6.1]  (5.74,6.1]  (4.66,5.02] (5.38,5.74] (5.38,5.74] (5.38,5.74] (6.1,6.46]  (5.02,5.38] (5.38,5.74]
[101] (6.1,6.46]  (5.74,6.1]  (6.82,7.18] (6.1,6.46]  (6.46,6.82] (7.54,7.9]  (4.66,5.02] (7.18,7.54] (6.46,6.82] (7.18,7.54]
[111] (6.46,6.82] (6.1,6.46]  (6.46,6.82] (5.38,5.74] (5.74,6.1]  (6.1,6.46]  (6.46,6.82] (7.54,7.9]  (7.54,7.9]  (5.74,6.1] 
[121] (6.82,7.18] (5.38,5.74] (7.54,7.9]  (6.1,6.46]  (6.46,6.82] (7.18,7.54] (6.1,6.46]  (5.74,6.1]  (6.1,6.46]  (7.18,7.54]
[131] (7.18,7.54] (7.54,7.9]  (6.1,6.46]  (6.1,6.46]  (5.74,6.1]  (7.54,7.9]  (6.1,6.46]  (6.1,6.46]  (5.74,6.1]  (6.82,7.18]
[141] (6.46,6.82] (6.82,7.18] (5.74,6.1]  (6.46,6.82] (6.46,6.82] (6.46,6.82] (6.1,6.46]  (6.46,6.82] (6.1,6.46]  (5.74,6.1] 
10 Levels: (4.3,4.66] (4.66,5.02] (5.02,5.38] (5.38,5.74] (5.74,6.1] (6.1,6.46] (6.46,6.82] (6.82,7.18] ... (7.54,7.9]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another trick. Some packages, like glmnet, *only* take as inputs the design matrix and the response variable. If one wants to fit a model with all interactions between features, she can't use the formula "y ~ .^2". Using `expand.grid()` allows us to take advantage of the powerful array indexing and vector operations of R.

```
interArray=function(X){
    n=ncol(X)
    ind=expand.grid(1:n,1:n)
    return(X[,ind[,1]]*X[,ind[,2]])
}

> X
          X1         X2
1 0.96852363 0.33827107
2 0.08012755 0.69159828
3 0.10167545 0.38119304
4 0.06699458 0.41756415
5 0.08187816 0.09805104

> interArray(X)
           X1          X2        X1.1        X2.1
1 0.938038022 0.327623524 0.327623524 0.114427316
2 0.006420424 0.055416073 0.055416073 0.478308177
3 0.010337897 0.038757974 0.038757974 0.145308137
4 0.004488274 0.027974536 0.027974536 0.174359821
5 0.006704033 0.008028239 0.008028239 0.009614007
```

Comment: If a modelling function doesn't accept a formula (which is very rare!) wouldn't it be better to construct the design matrix with `model.matrix`?

Comment: Nice one. I didn't know of the existence of this function. The function above is equivalent to model.matrix(~.^2 -1,X) But regarding passing matrices, aside from glmnet, it is frequent for me to pass array pointers to custom C functions. Indeed, I wouldn't know how to pass a formula to a function. Do you have a toy example?

Answer (score 5):

One of my favorite, if not somewhat unorthodox tricks, is the use of `eval()` and `parse()`.  This example perhaps illustrates how it can be helpful

```
NY.Capital <- 'Albany'
state <- 'NY'
parameter <- 'Capital'
eval(parse(text=paste(state, parameter, sep='.')))

[1] "Albany"
```

This type of situation occurs more often than not, and use of `eval()` and `parse()` can help address it.  Of course, I welcome any feedback on alternative ways of coding this up.

Comment: This can be done as well with named vector elements.

Comment: library(fortunes);fortune(106) 

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)

Comment: Here's an example where eval() and parse() can be useful.  This involves a Bioconductor package, e.g. hgu133a.db and where you are trying to obtain various pieces of information about a probeset id.  For example:

library(hgu133a.db)
parameter <- 'SYMBOL'
mget('202431_s_at', env=eval(parse(text=paste('hgu133a',parameter, sep=''))))
parameter <- 'ENTREZID'
mget('202431_s_at', env=eval(parse(text=paste('hgu133a',parameter, sep=''))))

Comment: As Dirk says, this is better done with named vector elements, or ` get(paste(state, parameter, sep='.'))`

Comment: @Hadley, didn't know that you could use get() that way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`set.seed()` sets the random number generator state.

For example:

```
> set.seed(123)
> rnorm(1)
[1] -0.5604756
> rnorm(1)
[1] -0.2301775
> set.seed(123)
> rnorm(1)
[1] -0.5604756
```

Comment: super useful with examples that use random functions... helps get everyone on the same page

Answer (score 5):

For those who are writing C to be called from R: `.Internal(inspect(...))` is handy.  For example:

```
> .Internal(inspect(quote(a+2)))
  @867dc28 06 LANGSXP g0c0 [] 
  @8436998 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,gp=0x4000] "+"
  @85768b0 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(2)] "a"
  @8d7bf48 14 REALSXP g0c1 [] (len=1, tl=0) 2
```

Answer (score 4):

d = '~/R Code/Library/'

files = list.files(d,'.r$')

for (f in files) {
    if (!(f == 'mysource.r' )) {
        print(paste('Sourcing',f))
        source(paste(d,f,sep=''))
    }
}

I use the above code to source all the files in a directory at start up with various utility programs I use in my interactive session with R.  I am sure there are better ways but I find it useful for my work. The line that does this is as follows.

source("~/R Code/Library/mysource.r")

Comment: Don't do it. Write a package.

Comment: Thanks.  I have been looking at a thread or two on roxygen and it seems I am probably at the level where I should try writing a simple self use package.

Answer (score 3):

To perform an operation on a number of variables in a data frame. This is stolen from subset.data.frame.

```
get.vars<-function(vars,data){
    nl <- as.list(1L:ncol(data))
    names(nl) <- names(data)
    vars <- eval(substitute(vars), nl, parent.frame())
    data[,vars]
    #do stuff here
}

get.vars(c(cyl:hwy,class),mpg)
```

Comment: This seems cool at first, but this sort of code will cause you no end of trouble in the long run.  It's always better to be explicit.

Comment: hum, I've been using this trick quite a bit as of late. Could you be more specific about its unbounded trouble?

Comment: Maybe hadley is suggesting using the plyr package instead?

Comment: No, this isn't a veiled suggestion to use plyr instead.

The basically problem with your code is that it is semantically lazy -  instead of making the user explicitly spell out what they want, you do some "magic" to guess.  The problem with this is that it makes the function very hard to program with - i.e. it's difficult to write a function that calls `get.vars` without jumping through a whole lot of hoops.

Answer (score 3):

I've posted this once before but I use it so much I thought I'd post it again. Its just a little function to return the names and position numbers of a data.frame. Its nothing special to be sure, but I almost never make it through a session without using it multiple times.

```
##creates an object from a data.frame listing the column names and location
```

namesind=function(df){

```
temp1=names(df)
temp2=seq(1,length(temp1))
temp3=data.frame(temp1,temp2)
names(temp3)=c("VAR","COL")
return(temp3)
rm(temp1,temp2,temp3)
```

}

ni <- namesind

Comment: This is a really a one-liner:
`data.frame(VAR = names(df), COL = seq_along(df))`

Comment: very elegant, maybe I'll switch it to 
ni <- function(df){data.frame(VAR = names(df), COL = seq_along(df))}

Comment: I use:

data.frame(colnames(the.df))

Answer (score 3):

I mention this one because there is a distinct lack of examples using it on SO.

The new(ish) aggregate.formula syntax makes it much more flexible and useful than the old generic aggregate.  It keeps the name of the aggregated variable, is more compact than the list syntax, and it allows you to do multiple variables at the same time including dot notation on either side of the formula.

use

```
newdf <- aggregate( cbind(rt, acc) ~ x + y + subj, olddf, mean )
```

instead of...

```
newdf <- with( olddf, aggregate( rt, list(x = x, y = y, subj = subj), mean ))
names(newdf)[4] <- 'rt'
newdf$acc <- with( olddf, 
                   aggregate( acc, list(x = x, y = y, subj = subj), mean ))[,4]
```

Perhaps as a bit of a side note... the aggregate.data.frame examples in ?aggregate as well. The function does a lot of things people don't know about.

Answer (score 2):

As a recent R addict, I love the ?function_name and use it all the time

-k

Comment: @Dirk: Just a side note. You are everywhere :) !

Comment: That's just a lack of focus :)   In Emacs/ESS, ?? and ??? also work but I use them way less.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I cannot comment (maybe it has to do with this "reputation" business)

Anyway further to the RGoogleDocs tips above:

`ps <-readline(prompt="get the password in ")`

This won't work from within Emacs, which I like to use for R, with ESS of course.

On Linux, you can use zenity to get the password from user input, and set it to hide the input, so as an additional benefit, your password is not plaintext on your screen:

`mypass <- system("zenity --entry --hide-text",intern=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

I like the expressiveness of the language, e.g. selects:

```
df[df$col > something, c('col2', 'col3')]
```

tapply:

```
tapply(df$col_value, df$col_factor, function)
```

etc.