# Assigning values from if-else blocks (how does it work?)

Tags: r, if-statement

I [recently discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295955/what-is-the-most-useful-r-trick/1826778#1826778) that you can conditionally assign a value with an if-else block.

```
y <- if(condition) 1 else 2
```

I realise that the use case for this is limited: if you have vectorised code, you would use the `ifelse` function instead.  There is a performance benefit: `if-else` runs about 35x faster than `ifelse` in the scalar case on my machine (though you need to call it millions of times to notice much of a difference).

What is bugging me is that I can't work out why this code works—I was amazed that it doesn't just throw an error.

Another example suggests that if blocks behave like functions—they automatically return the last value in the block (though you can't use a `return` statement in them).

```
y <- if(TRUE) 
{
   y <- 3
   4
}    # y is 4
```

Based on this, I guessed that maybe another environment was created when you entered an if block, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

```
if(TRUE) sys.frames()    # NULL
```

Can anyone tell me what is happening under the hood, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me focus on

> What is bugging me is that I can't
>   work out why this code works—I was
>   amazed that it doesn't just throw an
>   error.

Why do you think so?   What happens is that we have

1. `y` being assigned an expression
2. that expression being an if `if() ...`
3. leading to either a `TRUE` or `FALSE` in the test
4. leading to either one of the two branches being entered
5. leading to the respective code being evaluated
6. leading to its final value being the value of the right-hand-side
7. leading to this value being assigned to `y`

Seems logical to me.

Comment: Perhaps I'm over (or under) thinking this, and we can put it down to very clever parsing.  For the record, when you try something like this in MATLAB, you get an error: `Illegal use of reserved keyword "if".`

Comment: R is not MATLAB though-- there is no reason why it would have to follow MATLAB's rules.  Here the value of the last statement evaluated in the if block is being assigned to y.  That statement was the scalar 4.

Comment: Python also breaks, as does C# (though you can use the `?` operator, as Ken pointed out).  I think the critical bit is that the right hand side of the statement is considered as an expression and evaluated **before** the assignment is made.

Answer (score 5):

Control structures such as `if(....)  ... else ...` are equivalent to function calls with the relevant (lazy-evaluated) subexpressions as the argument:

```
`if`(TRUE, "yes", "no")
```

Basically, `if` is a *special primitive* function:

```
R> sapply(ls("package:base", all=TRUE), function(x) is.primitive(get(x)))["if"]
  if 
TRUE 
R> sapply(ls("package:base", all=TRUE), function(x) typeof(get(x)))["if"]
       if 
"special"
```

The relevant section (Section 3.2.1) in the [R Language Definition manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html) says:

Because if/else statements are the same as other statements you can assign the value of them. The two examples below are equivalent.

```
R> if( any(x <= 0) ) y <- log(1+x) else y <- log(x)
R> y <- if( any(x <= 0) ) log(1+x) else log(x)
```

Comment: @rcs: Thanks for the reference.  I should probably work my way through the manual to get a clearer idea of what R is doing.

Comment: I can also recommend Chapter 13 (How R Works) in Software for Data Analysis - Programming with R (John Chambers)

Answer (score 3):

About second part of your question - `{}` is used to group expressions, it works diffrent than in a function definition. As you can read in `help("Paren")`:

> For `‘{’`, the result of the last expression evaluated.

But all expressions are evaluated in the current environment:

```
y <- if (TRUE) {
    print(paste("Current frame:",sys.nframe()))
    y <- 3
    z <- 5
    4
}
# [1] "Current frame: 0"
# result:
y # [1] 4
z # [1] 5

# compare to use function:
v <- if(TRUE) (function(){      
    print(paste("Current frame:",sys.nframe()))
    v <- 3
    w <- 5
    4
})()
# [1] "Current frame: 1"
v # [1] 4
w # Error: object 'w' not found
```

Conclusion is **blocks don't behave like functions**.

edit:
If you want use blocks as function you could use `local`:

```
a <- if (TRUE) local({
    print(paste("Current frame:",sys.nframe()))
    a <- 3
    b <- 5
    4
})
# [1] "Current frame: 6"
a # [1] 4
b # Error: object 'b' not found
```

Then you could use `return` too:

```
a <- if (TRUE) local({
    print(paste("Current frame:",sys.nframe()))
    a <- 3
    b <- 5
    return(7)
    4
})
# [1] "Current frame: 6"
a # [1] 7
b # Error: object 'b' not found
```

Comment: @Marek: An interesting analysis.  I hadn't considered that ( and { would be functions.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really very deep - many languages use the "val = x ? y : z" construct for this.  In R, that's just folded into an if/else construct, so you write "val = if(x) y else z" instead.

Comment: Good point &ndash; I suppose it does parse in more or less the same way as a ternary operator.