# Is there a precedence for publishing data via a package in R?

Tags: r, package, data-cleaning

In discussions of how to organize workflows and projects in R it is often recommended that a [package be written](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2258292/1078621) to document &  share work.  I was wondering: is there **any precedence for using an R package to publish & make publicly available data** (as well as associated materials such as metadata, custom data processing tools, etc), either via CRAN or some other outlet?  I work with data that requires multiple stages of cleaning, eg basic removal of typos, rudimentary record matching & custom imputation of missing data, followed by various forms of reshaping & aggregation for specific analyses.  An R package seems like a useful way to document and present the data & methods used to produce.  The main downside is the investment in time.  The upsides appear numerous: high standards of documentation for future students in our lab, my future self, and other potential users, full reproducibility, and a platform for updating the data as more is collected.

**Some context:**  Publishing data as flat files + meta data  is increasingly common in my field via online appendices hosted by journals; a [third-party website](http://datadryad.org/) is also popular.  Reproduction of figures & analyses is usually possible, but data are sometimes highly "massaged" & steps in processing cannot always be reproduced, sometimes limiting the ability to carry out alternative analyses.  My adviser & I would like to publish data from the 1st 10 years of a 15 year longitudinal study.  I already need to clean up my data processing scripts for passing on to future students/co-authors, which alone might make a package for in-house use useful.

Comment: The Bioconductor project uses packages to publish data all the time.

Answer (score 2):

[BioConductor](http://www.bioconductor.org) does it a lot: see [this page about 'experiment data' packages](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.13/data/experiment/).

Anecdotally, CRAN has a few data packages as eg [EcDat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ecdat/index.html).

But in general, maybe a local archive would be better approach?  I happen to have put [a recent package](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) onto CRAN which can help there.