# What is the difference between `transform` and `within`

Tags: r

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295955/what-is-the-most-useful-r-trick) excellent post i came across `within` and `transform`.

Reading both help files i unfortunatly did not fully understand what the differnence is...

I tried something like:

```
df <- data.frame(A = runif(5), B = rnorm(5))
A=1:5
within(df, C<-A+B)
transform(df,C=A+B)
```

Both times the Output was:

```
          A          B         C
1 0.2326266  1.3237210 1.5563476
2 0.4581693 -0.2605674 0.1976018
3 0.6431078  0.5920021 1.2351099
4 0.9682578  1.1964012 2.1646590
5 0.9889942  0.5468008 1.5357950
```

So both seem to create a new enwironment as they are ignoring `A=1:5` within the evaluation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`within` lets you use an earlier defined variable later but not `transform`:

```
within(BOD, { a <- demand; b <- a }) # ok
transform(BOD, a = demand, b = a) # error
```

Note that I had defined a variation of `transform` that acts more like `within` a number of years ago [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-September/139952.html) where it is called `my.transform`.  Using that we could write the above like this:

```
my.transform(BOD, a = demand, b = a) # ok
```

In the above examples `within` (or `my.transform`) would be better but in the following `transform` is better:

```
transform(BOD, Time = demand, demand = Time) # swap columns
within(BOD, { Time <- demand; demand <- Time }) # oops
```

(To perform the swap with `within` would require that we define a temporary.)

### EDIT

`my.transform` is now in the gsubfn CRAN package where it is called `transform2` .   `mutate` in dplyr works from left to right.

Note that `transform`, `transform2` and `mutate` each work slightly differently. The RHS `transform` arguments all refer to the original values.  The RHS of `mutate` arguments refer to the most recent left-to-right value.  `transform2` figures out the dependencies and uses those so that a dependent can come before or after the argument in which it used.

Comment: So, if `within` is more powerful than `transform` (and just as easy to use), and their respective help pages indicate `transform` is intended for the interactive session whereas `within` appears to have no such restriction, what's the advantage of using `transform`?

Comment: I almost never use `within` and use `transform` a lot so transform is really more suitable for most common usages.