# R how to avoid "for" when I want to go through dataframe

Tags: r, database

give a brief example.
I have data frame `data1`.

```
name<-c("John","John","Mike","Amy".....) 
nationality<-c("Canada","America","Spain","Japan".....)
data1<-data.frame(name,nationality....)
```

which mean the people is from different countries
each people is specialize by his name and country, and no repeat.

the second data frame is

```
name2<-c("John","John","Mike","John",......)
nationality2<-c("Canada","Canada","Canada".....)
score<-c(87,67,98,78,56......)
data2<-data.frame(name2,nationality2,score)
```

every people is promised to have 5 rows in `data2`, which means they have 5 scores but they are in random order.

what I want to do is to know every person's 5 scores, but I didn't care what his name is and where he is from.

the final data frame I want to have is

```
   score1   score2  score3  score4   score5
1    89        89       87     78        90
2    ...
3    ...
```

every row represent one person 5 scores but I don't care who he is.
my data number is so large so I can not use `for` function.
what can I do?

Comment: the final dataframe I want to have has five column and each row represent one person's five scores.

Comment: it seems that you don't use data1 here do you ?

Comment: oh sorry, I forget to tell that data2 just have many data. But I am just interested in those people appearing in data1.

Comment: so I have to go through every row of data1 and I used For function which was terrible

Comment: ok i'll modify my answer below then

Comment: there you go tell me if it's good enough

Comment: For your issue with whatever you were doing in your for loop, I think you need to investigate the subset function and the %in% operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that's what you're asking:

```
data1 <- data.frame(name  = c("John","Mike","Amy"),
                nationality = c("America","Canada","Canada"))

data2 <- data.frame(name2 = rep(c("John","Mike","Amy","Jack","John"),each = 5),
                    score = sample(100,25), nationality2 =rep(c("America","Canada","Canada","Canada","Canada"),each = 5))

data3 <- merge(data2,data1,by.x=c("name2","nationality2"),by.y=c("name","nationality"))
data3$name_country <- paste(data3$name2,data3$nationality2)
all_scores_list <- tapply(data3$score,data3$name_country,c)
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,all_scores_list))

# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# Amy Canada   57 69 90 81 50
# John America  4 92 75 15  2
# Mike Canada  25 86 51 20 12
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: but, actually John could come from America or Canada, and I am interested in John from America

Comment: I used merge instead of subset %in%, that's more convenient for several columns, then created a name_country column to group on

Comment: That is what I want !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Thank you very much!  感谢！BTW， how could I get familiar with advanced programming technique like this one. The book I could find in China is quite basic and simple.

Comment: The official documentation is usually very good, so 1st step is to learn not to get scared by it and try the example you find when you execute `?merge` , `?subset` , `?match` , `?apply` `?do.call` etc. personally wouldn't like to learn R from books but that's just me. lookup functions in stack overflow will also teach you a lot. And recently I found this cool link too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295955/what-is-the-most-useful-r-trick . I can explain more in the answer if needed, and you can validate it if you're happy with it

Comment: would you mind helping me with anther question? I have post it

Comment: oh, I don't know how to accept. I don't even know I should accept an answer. Sorry.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Apology. The arrow is quite confusing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44468974/r-how-to-get-data-according-to-stock-code-and-dateavoid-for-function. this is the link.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is an already accepted answer which uses base R I would like to suggest a solution which uses the convenient `dcast()` function for reshaping from wide to long form instead of using `tapply()` and repeated calls to `rbind()`:

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
dcast(setDT(data2)[setDT(data1), on = c(name2 = "name", nationality2 = "nationality")],
      name2 + nationality2 ~ paste0("score", rowid(rleid(name2, nationality2))),
                                    value.var = "score")
```

returns

```
   name2 nationality2 score1 score2 score3 score4 score5
1:   Amy       Canada     93     91     73      8     79
2:  John      America      3     77     69     89     31
3:  Mike       Canada     76     92     46     47     75
```

Comment: great thanks. Another example for learning data.table. It seems that this package is quietly powerful in dealing with data.frame