# How to get data according to stock code and date while avoiding for loops?

Tags: r

I have two data frame. `data1` consist of three columns, one is stock code like 600287, another is its earning announcement day like 2015-09-07, the third is its announcement earning (earning per share) like 0.8. This data frame is in random order, it consists of different stock and different announcement days because it covers a time from 2014 to 2016. Every stock could announce 4 times a year and I have 2400 stocks in this data frame.

```
code1     day1       announcement
600181   2015-09-08       0.9
```

`data2` are stock daily performance data. It has daily return rates of 2500 stocks from 2014-2015. So it has over 2 million rows which is the reason I'm looking for an efficient solution. `data2` also has code numbers and dates.

```
code2      day2        return
600298    2016-08-09    0.03
```

I'm researching company post-announcement stock price reaction. Basically, for example, if company "A" announces its earning on 2016-09-08, I have to know every return rate of stock "A" in the next 5 dealing days (including 2015-9-8 if it is a dealing day). Dealing days for every stock are different but if and only if this day appears in `data2` it is a dealing day of stock "A".

The difficulty here is that stock "A" announces on 2015-06-09 but this day does not appear in `data2` of stock "A" (this can be due to the fact that 2015-06-09 is a Sunday which is not a dealing day in China). What I did is using the `difftime()` function and then order it but this is slow!

The final data frame I want to get is like this (7 columns)

```
code     announce-day    d1      d2     d3      d4     d5
600287    2015-08-07     0.08   0.06   0.02    0.01  -0.02
```

(again I want to say day1 could be 2015-08-07 if this day is a dealing day. It could also be 2015-08-09. The only judge is it appears first in `data2` after 2015-08-07)

I have been working on this problem for so long and I can't fix it.
I give a brief example.

```
code1<-"600187"
day1<-as.Date("2016-10-09")  ##stock 600187 announce on 2016-10-09
announcement<-0.8
data1<-data.frame(code1, day1,announcement)
code2<-c(rep("600187",10),"600234")
x<-as.Date("2016-07-08")
x<-seq(x,x+4,by=1)
y<-as.Date("2016-10-11")
y<-seq(y,y+4,by=1)
day2<-c(x,y,as.Date("2016-12-30"))
return<-"whatever"
data2<-data.frame(code2,day2,return)
```

In this case `data1` only consist of one announcement of one stock. The announce day is 2016-10-09 but the next day to appear in `data2` is 2016-10-11.

Here is my for-loop code, I still use test data because I don't know how to uplode the whole data.

```
require(snow)
code1<-c("600187","600111","600111")
day1<-as.Date(c("2016-10-09","2011-02-02","2011-09-09"))
announcement<-c(0.8,0.2,0.2)
data1<-data.frame(code1,day1,announcement,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
code2<-c(rep("600187",10),"600234")
x<-as.Date("2016-07-08")
x<-seq(x,x+4,by=1)
y<-as.Date("2016-10-11")
y<-seq(y,y+4,by=1)
day2<-c(x,y,as.Date("2016-12-30"))
return<-seq(from = 0.01, by = 0.005, length.out = length(day2))
data2<-data.frame(code2,day2,return,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
mtl<-function(ichunk,data2,data1){
stime<-data1$day1
 cd<-data1$code1
k<-1
houxu<-data.frame(cd=NA,date=NA,l1=NA,l2=NA,l3=NA,l4=NA,l5=NA)
  for(i in ichunk){
a<-subset(data2,code2==cd[i])
   a<-transform(a,time=difftime(day2,stime[i],units="days"))
a<-subset(a,time>=0)
 a<-subset(a,rank(time)%in%1:5)
 a<-a[order(a$time),] 
  q<-c(cd[i],1,a$return)   ##the 1 is used for date, 
 if(length(q)<7)
  { houxu[k,]<-NA} else {houxu[k,]<-q}     
  k<-k+1}
 houxu[,2]<-stime[ichunk]  ##the column of day 
return(houxu)}
mutlinks<-function(cls,data2,data1){
  n<-nrow(data1)
 options(warn=-1) 
 k<-ceiling(n/2)
ichunks<-list(1:k,(k+1):n)
options(warn=0) 
  df<-clusterApply(cl=cls,fun=mtl,ichunks,data2,data1) 


 do.call(rbind,df) }

cl<-makeCluster(type="SOCK",c("localhost","localhost")) 
bxdf<-mutlinks(cl,data2,data1)  
bxdf<-na.omit(bxdf)
```

This code will take 16minutes, not so long

Comment: for-loop doesn't work here. I need a solution using vectorisation intelligently

Comment: With `data.table`'s rolling join the task can be achieved without any `for` loops.

Comment: In some of your comments to answers, you have mentioned that you have a code using `for` loops which returns correct results. Please, can you [edit] your question and add the complete code you are using? Thank you.

Comment: I have post my code, still use some test data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the OP, `data2` *has daily return rates of 2500 stocks from 2014-2015 with over 2 million rows*.

I recommend to use the `data.table` package for this task for two reasons: It's designed for fast joins on large data, and it it allows us to use a *rolling join*. There is no need to use `for` loops for this task.

So, with sample data sets given by the OP, the `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
# coerce to data.table, 
# set keys to make sure data are properly ordered,
# add column to join on
setDT(data1, key = c("code1", "day1"))[, join_day := day1] # announcements
setDT(data2, key = c("code2", "day2"))[, join_day := day2] # returns

# join on stock code and do a rolling join on day
data1[data2, on = c(code1 = "code2", "join_day"), roll = TRUE]
```

returns

```
     code1       day1 announcement   join_day       day2   return
 1: 600187       <NA>           NA 2016-07-08 2016-07-08 whatever
 2: 600187       <NA>           NA 2016-07-09 2016-07-09 whatever
 3: 600187       <NA>           NA 2016-07-10 2016-07-10 whatever
 4: 600187       <NA>           NA 2016-07-11 2016-07-11 whatever
 5: 600187       <NA>           NA 2016-07-12 2016-07-12 whatever
 6: 600187 2016-10-09          0.8 2016-10-11 2016-10-11 whatever
 7: 600187 2016-10-09          0.8 2016-10-12 2016-10-12 whatever
 8: 600187 2016-10-09          0.8 2016-10-13 2016-10-13 whatever
 9: 600187 2016-10-09          0.8 2016-10-14 2016-10-14 whatever
10: 600187 2016-10-09          0.8 2016-10-15 2016-10-15 whatever
11: 600234       <NA>           NA 2016-12-30 2016-12-30 whatever
```

The *rolling join* has copied the announcement of 2016-10-09 to all returns of the matching stock *after* that day. This is called *LOCF* or *last observation carried forward*. It will do so until the next announcement for that particular stock is encountered.

The rows with NAs can be removed from the result with:

```
data1[data2, on = c(code1 = "code2", "join_day"), roll = TRUE, nomatch = 0]
```

which yields

```
    code1       day1 announcement   join_day       day2   return
1: 600187 2016-10-09          0.8 2016-10-11 2016-10-11 whatever
2: 600187 2016-10-09          0.8 2016-10-12 2016-10-12 whatever
3: 600187 2016-10-09          0.8 2016-10-13 2016-10-13 whatever
4: 600187 2016-10-09          0.8 2016-10-14 2016-10-14 whatever
5: 600187 2016-10-09          0.8 2016-10-15 2016-10-15 whatever
```

---

Now, the OP has requested to study returns of the next five trading days on and after the day of announcement. The rolling join allows to limit how far values are carried forward but that works on the *difference* (in days here) but not on the *number* of rows. As there are gaps in the sequence of trading days, this feature can't be used directly for that purpose. Instead, `head()` is used to pick the first `n_days` *rows* in each group.

As the given data samples are limited in size, let's assume we want to observe returns on the next *two* trading days for demonstration and test:

```
n_days <- 2L
joined <- data1[data2, on = c(code1 = "code2", "join_day"), roll = TRUE, nomatch = 0][
  order(day2), head(.SD, n_days), .(code1, day1)]
```

`joined` is now reduced to contain `n_days` of return values on or after each announcement day of each stock:

```
    code1       day1 announcement   join_day       day2   return
1: 600187 2016-10-09          0.8 2016-10-11 2016-10-11 whatever
2: 600187 2016-10-09          0.8 2016-10-12 2016-10-12 whatever
```

Finally, the OP wants the result to be reshaped from long to wide format. This can be done using `dcast()`:

```
dcast(joined, code1 + day1 ~ paste0("d", rowid(code1, day1)), 
      value.var = "return")
```

which yields:

```
    code1       day1       d1       d2
1: 600187 2016-10-09 whatever whatever
```

#### Potential performance improvement by reducing the data volume

As already mentioned above, the `roll` parameter allows us to limit how far values are carried forward. Together with `nomatch = 0`, this can be used to reduce the data volume resulting from the rolling join operation. However, the `roll` parameter must be choosen carefully due to gaps in the sequence of return days. Therefore, the length of the longest gap plus the number of trading days is used:

```
max_gap <- data2[order(day2), max(diff(day2))]
joined <- data1[data2, on = c(code1 = "code2", "join_day"), roll = max_gap + n_days,
                nomatch = 0][
                  order(day2), head(.SD, n_days), .(code1, day1)]
```

#### Data

```
data1 <- structure(list(code1 = structure(1L, .Label = "600187", class = "factor"), 
    day1 = structure(17083, class = "Date"), announcement = 0.8, 
    join_day = structure(17083, class = "Date")), .Names = c("code1", 
"day1", "announcement", "join_day"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
data2 <- structure(list(code2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("600187", "600234"), class = "factor"), 
    day2 = structure(c(16990, 16991, 16992, 16993, 16994, 17085, 
    17086, 17087, 17088, 17089, 17165), class = "Date"), return = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "whatever"), 
    join_day = structure(c(16990, 16991, 16992, 16993, 16994, 
    17085, 17086, 17087, 17088, 17089, 17165), class = "Date")), .Names = c("code2", 
"day2", "return", "join_day"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It is quite amazing!!!! You are my idol. For this excellent answer, I am going to learn this package! Would you give me more advice in learning this packages as it seems quite different from the base package in dealing with dataframe

Comment: joined <- data1[data2, on = c(code1 = "code2", "join_day"), roll = TRUE, nomatch = 0][
  order(day2), head(.SD, n_days), .(code1, day1)]      and    joined <- data1[data2, on = c(code1 = "code2", "join_day"), roll = max_gap + n_days,
                nomatch = 0][
                  order(day2), head(.SD, n_days), .(code1, day1)]  will result in different data.frame with different rows!! I don't know why? What's wrong? The final dataframe has 8163 and 7751 rows respectively.

Comment: actually I have used the for-loop and the final data.frame has 9033 rows. But joined <- data1[data2, on = c(code1 = "code2", "join_day"), roll = max_gap + n_days,
                nomatch = 0][
                  order(day2), head(.SD, n_days), .(code1, day1)]
dtdf<-dcast(joined, code1 + day1 ~ paste0("d", rowid(code1, day1)), 
      value.var = "return")   dd<-na.omit(dtdf)  will result in a data.frame with 7751 rows

Comment: I have tested my for-loop(using concurrent computation) and I think it is right. BTW your code is fast so I really want to learn!

Comment: and actually I merge for-loop-fiinal-data and your-method-final-data, I found they have 7500 same rows

Comment: @JingnanLai Thank you for your feedback. For learning `data.table`, https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started is a good starting point, in particular, the vignettes and the FAQ.

Comment: @JingnanLai Concerning the discrepancies, I was sure this will happen because production data are always good for any surprise. A code which is working on a made-up sample data set may break because of unforeseen combinations of data in a real world data set. BTW, ordering the data might be crucial, here. Do see a chance to subset your production data where the 3 different approaches still produce different results?

Comment: what does it mean by ordering the data? Your code is quite robust and so does mine. Could you give me more link (or example) why this would happen? As the loss is about 4%. And the same rows is only 7500, sth must be wrong.

Comment: and I tried data1 in 200 rows(it used to have 9410), still your answer missed sth

Comment: @JingnanLai I feel challenged to get this working to your expectations but it's difficult to debug a code which works well on a small sample data set but fails on production data without access to the full data. I see 3 possibilities: (a) Please, provide a larger sample data set (`data1`, `data2`) which still shows the discrepancies between the 2 codes. (b) Please, somehow provide access to your full data. (c) with all respect, if rows are missing in one result, the additional rows in the other result could be considered as surplus or duplicates.

Comment: yes,I want to provide you full data. could you remain your email?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146659/discussion-between-uwe-block-and-jingnan-lai).

Answer (score 1):

The for-loop I have written gives you the result you want for your example. But I don't know whether its performance is acceptable for the large data set of yours. However, I am sure there are a lot of ways to optimise the loop.

```
code1<-"600187"
day1<-as.Date("2016-10-09")  ##stock 600187 announce on 2016-10-09
announcement<-0.8
data1<-data.frame(code1, day1,announcement)
code2<-c(rep("600187",10),"600234")
x<-as.Date("2016-07-08")
x<-seq(x,x+4,by=1)
y<-as.Date("2016-10-11")
y<-seq(y,y+4,by=1)
day2<-c(x,y,as.Date("2016-12-30"))
return<-seq(from = 0.01, by = 0.005, length.out = length(day2))
data2<-data.frame(code2,day2,return)


df3 <- data.frame(data1$code1, data1$day1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
colnames(df3) <- c("code", "announce-day", "r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5")
`%notin%` <- function(x,y){
  !(x %in% y) 
}
for(i in 1:nrow(df3)){
  data.code <- data.frame(data2$day2[as.numeric(data2$code2) ==
                          as.numeric(df3$code[i])],
                          data2$return[as.numeric(data2$code2) ==
                          as.numeric(df3$code[i])])
  colnames(data.code) <- c("day","return") 
  start.date <- df3$`announce-day`[i]
  while(start.date %notin% data.code$day){
    start.date <- start.date + 1
  }
  index <- which(start.date == data.code$day)[1]
  df3$r1[i] <- data.code$return[index]
  df3$r2[i] <- data.code$return[index + 1]
  df3$r3[i] <- data.code$return[index + 2]
  df3$r4[i] <- data.code$return[index + 3]
  df3$r5[i] <- data.code$return[index + 4]
}
```

Comment: alomost there. Maybe I didn't make it clear. If A company announce on 2016-09-09, and suppose  it is Friday and this day could be included. But next day is Saturday, which is not dealing day. so df3$r2[i] <- data.code$return[data.code$day == start.date + 1] was wrong, I suppose order the df3 in date.

Comment: so I change the for-loop like this
`
  data.code<-data.code[order(data.code$day),]
  while(start.date %notin% data.code$day){
    start.date <- start.date + 1
  }
  n<-with(data.code,which(day==start.date))
  df3$r1[i] <- data.code$return[n]
  df3$r2[i] <- data.code$return[n+1]
  df3$r3[i] <- data.code$return[n+2]
  df3$r4[i] <- data.code$return[n+3]
  df3$r5[i] <- data.code$return[n+4]
}`

Comment: the for loop does not work. 30 minutes passed and still no result. data1 has 9000 rows and data2 has 2 million rows.

Comment: I see the problem – missed that the weekend can also disrupt the return series. I have edited the original answer to account for that.  Personally, I would try avoiding `order` in a loop. I can imagine it to be computationally intensive for so many rows. Just make sure you have ordered `data2` properly. If it is still too slow, someone would have to come up with a solution using vectorisation intelligently.